# Camera settings not working properly

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, camera

I have a Lenovo Yoga 13, the first version (Type 2191) that's running the latest update of Windows 10 (10.0.18362 Build 18362). There used to be two places for camera settings, one simple with just brightness and contrast and one advanced. Back then I would usually have to go into the advanced settings after a reboot to reset them so that my camera image would not just be grey. Since the Lenovo and Windows have changed their layouts and settings and I can now only find settings in one place, Lenovo Vantage - Device Settings - Display & Camera. These are only the simple settings.

I am not sure if there is some old remnants of settings somewhere that I can't change but with the current options I can only get a very poor grey image from my built in camera.

This is basically as good as I can get it
[image]

Any ideas on how I can get the image quality back to somthing useful?

Answer (score 0):

Found this very helpful tutorial of how to access the advanced settings that I used to be able to launch from windows built in camera settings.

https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/access-advanced-settings-for-the-integrated-webcam-on-windows-10/